# When do I start seeing payments?

Tags: iphone, ios, report, app-store-connect, itunes-store

My app has been on the market for about a month and a half now, and in able to see daily sales, but when I go to monthly report, it shows nothing. How long does it take to start seeing some money? Also does apple send you a check? Or does it go strait into your bank account?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple pay out per region, and wait for the accrued sales value to reach a certain threshold before paying out, then pay out monthly (each month you've exceeded the threshold).

So, if your sales are low in a region, you won't see a monthly report for that region, and won't get paid until money has accrued for that region to above the threshold.

IIRC, they also sweep out any payments at the end of the year, even if the amount is below the threshold.

When Apple make a payment, it will be credited to your bank account.